# Ultra-fast bitmap rendering using WPF, best solution?

Tags: wpf, directx, managed, fpga

I'm getting from our hardware device (FPGA) roughly 20 frames per second (500x500 px) and I would like to render them as fast as possible. We basically get a frame buffer every 50 msec and if my rendering is too slow - well... I'm skipping frames.

My problem is to render from a C++/CLI driver to a WPF-based application. I know it's possible to host a DirectX window in a WPF aplication. What would be the fastest solution ?

Comment: Very interested to hear what people say about this.  By the way, what is the data format, raw 24-bit RGB ?

Comment: Have you tried using myImageElement.Source = BitmapSource.Create(...) 20 times per second to see how well it works?

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: data is 8-bit indexed with an hardcoded colormap / palette.

@Tergiver: this is what I do at the moment. And I reckon I have to call GC.Collect() manually - I would run out of RAM !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InteropBitmap is the fastest way to update video frames.  It's a bit more complicated than WriteableBitmap, but worth it for the performance.

I have an example here in one of my OSS projects.  It's hard-coded for 32 RGBA, but you can modify it for 24bit.

http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39341#809062

D3DImage is another fast way, but might be overkill in your situation.